# language dictionary for android

Tags: android, dictionary

I would like to create a simple dictionary language. For example, English-German dictionary.
I looked through the internet but have not found answers to my questions. Therefore, I will be very grateful if you answer my questions

1) Are there somewhere ready created a database of English words and their equivalents in another language ?? Do I have such a words database alone create and rewrite thousands of words and their equivalents in another language with a dictionary book??

2) Are there any ready library with appropriate methods that will allow you to easily make the dictionary language ??

3) Is there somewhere on the Internet describing an example of how to make the dictionary ??

Answer (score 1):

The [Internet Dictionary Project](http://www.june29.com/idp/IDPfiles.html) has text files of mappings from one language to another.  Once you have an electronic version of the items, creating a bit of code to search through a file for matches in Java, etc., is pretty trivial.  An example of such an app in C# can be found [here](http://c-sharp.wonderhowto.com/how-to/write-simple-dictionary-program-c-257869/).  All the best!

Comment: Has  Internet Dictionary Project  text files of mappings other languages. For example: English-Polish ,English - Russian ??

Comment: From their website, they only seem to have English to French, German, Italian, Latin, Portuguese and Spanish.  I am sure that there are other resources out there for other languages that you require (e.g. Russion / Polish) and as per your point 2, no, you should not have to rewrite thousands of words!